# Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = "<example>{{var=b|arg=args|link=c|testing=test1}}</example>";
```

How do I use regex to match `args`? In other words, I want to match the thing that follows `arg=` but before the next `|`.

Comment: Rebeca, what you already tried?

Comment: I hope you're not trying to perform any sort of XML or HTML parsing with regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
var match = str.match(/arg=([^|]+)/);
```

Then check if `match[1]` exists. And if it does - then it contains what you want

**UPD**:

as @nnnnnn pointed out - instead of checking for `match[1]` presence it would be more correct to check if `match` is not `null` like:

```
if (match) {
    // match[1] here contains required info
}
```

Comment: Note that checking `match[1]` will give an error if there was no match: you have to test if `match` is null...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var args = str.match(/arg=([^|]*)/);
if (args != null) {
   // args[1] contains the match...
}
```

That is, find `arg=` and then capture the zero or more following characters that aren't `|`.